# Python print and json.dumps changes float value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hitting below issue on a linux server with python 3.6.8.
Json.dumps() call with simple float variable gives different results in each run.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  8 2020, 16:04:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.200)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2373.0
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.28
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.28
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.3121632
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.28
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2341.0
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2341.0
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2373.0
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.28
>>> print(json.dumps(float(2341)))
2342.28
>>> print(json.__file__)
/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py
>>> exit()
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$
```

No issues with 'Int' variable.
Have verified files in python package folder, all seem intact.
No issues seen related to server's memory/cpu.
Rebooting server / reinstalling python package are not feasible options currently.
Need some pointers in debugging/fixing this further.

---- EDIT ----
Issue seen with print(float(x)) also

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  8 2020, 16:04:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.200)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(float(2341))
2341.0
>>> print(float(2341))
2341.0
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.312
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.3121632
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.312
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.312
>>> print(float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(float(2341))
2341.0
>>> print(float(2341))
2373.0
>>> exit()
```

----- EDIT ---- Different flavours of print + float. Same issue.

```
>>> x = float(2341)
>>> for _ in range(20): print(x)
... 
2342.312
2342.28
2342.28
2342.28
2342.312
2342.312
2373.0
2342.28
2373.0
2373.0
2373.0
2373.0
2342.3121632
2342.3121632
2373.0
2342.28
2373.0
2342.28
2342.28
2373.0
>>>
>>> for _ in range(20): print(2341.0)
... 
2373.0
2342.28
2342.312
2342.28
2342.28
2342.28
2342.28
2373.0
2342.28
2342.28
2373.0
2373.0
2342.28
2373.0
2342.312
2373.0
2373.0
2342.28
2342.3121632
2342.3121632
>>> 
>>> import builtins
>>> print(builtins.float(2341))
2342.28
>>> print(builtins.float(2341))
2373.0
>>> print(builtins.float(2341))
2342.3121632
>>> print(builtins.float(2341))
2373.0
>>>
```

Comment: Does `print(float(2341))` work correctly? What's the output of `x = float(2341)` `for _ in range(10): print(x, json.dumps(x))`?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this, which leads to to think something is wrong with your packages.

Comment: I don't have anything helpful to contribute except that I cannot reproduce your issue on Python 3.9.6, running Windows 10. Hope you figure this out.

Comment: This is *not valid behavior* in a normal install of Python. *Perhaps some code has **hijacked** the name `float` or the json module with a “for fun” version?*

Comment: Also, as previously asked, is the issue reproducible locally when (using `float` to keep the rest of the expression the same and) *not* using `json.dumps`?

Comment: Also, by “verified files”, is that via hash/binary comparison of a known good system or via less robust means?

Comment: Missed to update earlier. I cant repro this either in other servers. Issue is specific only to this particular server. print(float(2341)) gives same issue. Updated logs above.

Comment: I might consider a full file tree compare for the Python installs to try and isolate the difference, as the issue results from `float` alone (as opposed to the json module). For curiosity, happens when replacing `float` with `builtins.float` (after `import builtins`)? Or using `2341.0` (and avoiding `float` entirely)?

Comment: What about my other test, printing the same float object multiple times?

Comment: To “resolve” the issue, I’d make a *copy* of the current Python resources (all), because it’s satisfying to track down an issue (I’ve identified a single bit flip *once* before). Then I would “re-install” the same version of Python, using any relevant means — this could be copying files from a known good server, which probably goes hand-in-hand with a full file tree compare.

Comment: I've verified the package contents manually by comparing it with other server. I'll double check on this with more robust approach.

Comment: How about `print(list(str(2341.0)))`? To check whether `print` or your terminal are messing up float strings.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to be the normal behavior of `json.dumps()`. For that reason, the best thing to do here is to ensure that everything is working correctly and reinstall any packages or modules that are causing the problem. Specifically, try reinstalling the base Python interpreter and see what happens with `print(json.dumps(2341.0))` and other similar expressions. Additionally, if all else fails, you can always use a third-party library, like [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/).